# Updating multiple tables in one form in Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table

Seems there should be a super-quick Railsy way to do this, but excessive Googling has yielded nothing to clear things up.

OK. I need to update three tables from one form. The view part of the equation is well-documented (form_for, fields_for). But I'm unsure how to handle the form params that are sent to the update action in the parent controller. Note: The three tables all have a defined Rails association.

View:

```
 <% form_for @account do |a| %>

  <table>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td>
        <%= a.label :plan_id %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= a.text_field :plan_id %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td>
        <%= a.label :company %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= a.text_field :company %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <% fields_for @user do |u| %>

      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <%= u.label :first_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= u.text_field :fname %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <%= u.label :last_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= u.text_field :lname %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <%= u.label :email %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= u.text_field :email %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <%= u.label :phone %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= u.text_field :phone %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td>
          <%= u.label :title %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= u.text_field :title %>
        </td>
      </tr>  

    <% end %>

    <% fields_for @site do |s| %>

      <tr class="even">
        <td>
          <%= s.label :domain %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= s.text_field :domain_name %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="odd">
        <td> 
          <%= s.label :url %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= s.text_field :url %>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <% end %>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">  
          <%= a.submit :submit %>
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>

<% end %>
```

Update action of accounts controller (This doesn't work):

```
account = params[:account]
user = account
site = account

account.save!
user.save!
site.save!
```

How do I handle the params that are posted to the update action? It seems straightforward to create new records in three tables from one form, but I don't know how to update those same three tables from the same form.

Answer (score 0):

If accounts/users/sites are all related then your associations in your model will handle the "tables" for you.  You should be thinking about your problem in terms of models (ie: your domain/business problem).  Let's say that one user can have multiple accounts (otherwise, no point in the account model) and each account can own a site (web hosting management app?).

If you set up your associations in app/models/*.rb with the has_many etc relationships, the saving a form in the controller method (or in IRB) is pretty easy.  The controller code you have is not right at all.  You can't assign variables like that and expect Rails to do quite that much magic.

```
account.user = params[:user]
account.site = params[:site]
```

For nested forms.  If you can't get that to work, use `rails c`:

```
account = Account.new
user = User.new
site = Site.new
account.user = user
account.site = site
account.save  # will fail if you have constraints/validations
```

Get it to work in rails c and IRB and then look at your form and HTTP activity using Firebug or other browser tool.  Put this in your controller method `puts params` and you'll see how nested forms post.